# Difference between IOB and IOB2 format?

Tags: dataset, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I have to tag a dataset for NER. I came across [conll2002/esp](https://github.com/teropa/nlp/blob/master/resources/corpora/conll2002/esp.testa). What I understand so far, in IOB2 format if I want to tag '`Alex Larson is going to Los Angeles for a job interview with Candace Patrick`' it'll be like:

```
Alex B-PER
Larson I-PER
is O
going O
to O
Los B-LOC
Angeles I-LOC
for O
a O
job O
interview O
with O
Candace B-PER
Patrick I-PER
```

Am I right? What about IOB format?

Answer (score 5):

The difference is not related to the length of the named entities. Rather, it deals with how two adjacent named entities of the same type are labeled.

In IOB1 (IOB), B- is only used to separate two adjacent entities of the same type:

```
Today    O
Alice    I-PER
Bob      B-PER
and      O
I        O  # or I-PER if pronominals are being tagged
ate      O
lasagna  O
```

In IOB2, all entities begin with B-:

```
Today    O
Alice    B-PER
Bob      B-PER
and      O
I        O  # or B-PER if pronominals are being tagged
ate      O
lasagna  O
```

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside%E2%80%93outside%E2%80%93beginning_(tagging))

Answer (score 3):

**IOB**: Here, `I` is used for a token inside a chunk, `O` is used for a token outside a chunk and `B` is only used for the beginning token of a Named Entity (chunk) spanning more than one token.

```
Alex I-PER
is O
going O
to O
Los B-LOC
Angeles I-LOC
```

**IOB2**: It is same as IOB, except that the `B-` tag is used in the beginning of every chunk (i.e. all chunks start with the `B-` tag).

```
Alex B-PER
is O
going O
to O
Los B-LOC
Angeles I-LOC
```

Comment: What could be the reason that PyLighter marks each character as separate tag: `BIO HEALTH - ['B-company', 'I-company', 'I-company', 'I-company', 'I-company', 'I-company', 'I-company', 'I-company', 'I-company', 'I-company']`